# Is an isometric and bijective mapping between two metric spaces complete?

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

If I have the two metric spaces $(X,d_x)$ and $(Y,d_y)$ with the mapping $f : X \to Y$ that is both an isometry and bijection between X and Y.

How do I show that $(Y,d_y)$ is complete iff $(X,d_x)$ is complete?

Comment: are you assuming one of the spaces is complete?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. It is given the case that one of them are complete. Show that it must follow that the other metric must be complete as well.

Comment: Then you just need to show every Cauchy sequence maps to a Cauchy sequence (via $f$ and $f^{-1}$). Once you have that, you're done because a homeomorphism maps convergent sequences to convergent sequences (in both directions).

Comment: Thanks, Forever Mozart. If possible, could you refer/show me a more formal way of showing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a matter of understanding the concept of isometry as just being a compatible relabeling of the elements. Assume $Y$ is complete. Take a Cauchy sequence in $X$. The isometry gives you a sequence in $Y$. Show it is Cauchy, and hence converges. This gives you a limit in $Y$. You can apply the inverse of the isometry to get a point in $X$, and show that the original sequence converges to this point.

Comment: That was a very nice explanation. Could you refer/show me a more formal way of showing this?

Comment: @oliverg my answer is inches away from a formal proof, I just avoid using notation as much as I can in these answers because I'm writing them on a cell phone. You just need to fill in the details.

Answer (score 2):

Why would they be complete?

Consider e.q. $\Bbb Q\times\{0\}$ and $\Bbb Q\times\{1\}$ as subspaces of the real plane and $f:=(x,0)\mapsto (x,1)$.

Comment: Ah, very good! I am sorry, but I stated the question wrongly. If one of the metrics is complete then the other must be complete aswell (i.e. a bi implication).

I have edited the question to be accurate. But thanks a lot for making me realize this.